# How to promise an Array of Strings?

Tags: typescript

Is this the correct way of defining a promising array of strings?

```
Promise<Array<string>>
```

Or

```
Promise<string[]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct.

`Promise<string[]>` looks nicer, in my opinion.

In general: `type[] === Array<type>`

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the former is syntactic sugar for the latter.